# WMI query returning incomplete results

Tags: perl, wmi

I'm working on a perl script that is used to check whether a number of services are running. To achieve this, we are using WMI to query remote Windows servers:

```
my $WMI_locator = Win32::OLE->new('WbemScripting.SWbemLocator');
$WMI_locator->{Security_}->{AuthentificationLevel} = 6;
my $computer = $WMI_locator->ConnectServer($server, 'root\cimv2', $adminuser, $adminpasswd);
my $services = $computer->ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_Service', 'WQL', $flag_return_immediately | $flag_forward_only);
```

This code snippet works perfectly when executed on my dev laptop. However, strange things happen when I try to run it from the production server: for some remote windows computers, I can only get about half the Services list.

I have looked into this, and found that the issue is only happening on servers with a lot of services (around 150), and for which there's a difference in the average ping (~60ms on local, ~215ms on production server). The issue seems to come from WMI rather than perl; I have tried to query the servers from the DOS command line, and I'm getting an error when trying to get the services, although querying the CPU works just fine :

```
E:\>wmic /NODE:server /USER:adminuser /PASSWORD:adminpasswd SERVICE GET Caption, State
Node - server
ERROR:
Code = 0x800706be
Description = The remote procedure call failed.
Facility = Win32

E:\>wmic /NODE:server /USER:adminuser /PASSWORD:adminpasswd CPU GET Name, Status
Name                                             Status
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5650  @ 2.67GHz  OK
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5650  @ 2.67GHz  OK
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5650  @ 2.67GHz  OK
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5650  @ 2.67GHz  OK
```

Given that, I'm guessing the issue is network related, but we're now delving in a country I'm not familiar with. Is there some parameter I have missed and/or something wrong with the way I'm doing things?

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

This error is almost always (although not exclusively) caused by multiple instances of different versions of SQL server. To narrow down the problem try [WMI Diagnostic Utility](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7684), it's designed to help with this type of problem.